# Magento 2 custom module gives list page blank

Tags: magento2, layout, collection, xml, router

I have custom module the `news_index_index` file is as bellow.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
       <block class="Custom\News\Block\Frontend\News" name="newscoll.collall" template="Custom_News::news.phtml" /> 
       </referenceContainer>  
    </body>
</page>
```

In footer i have called it there it works file with

```
{{block class="Custom\News\Block\Frontend\Newsslide" template="news_slide.phtml"}}
```

But `news_index_index.xml` it doesn't load list file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well as I see you haven't spcified the `layout` in your module's layout file.

Specify it as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
       <block class="Custom\News\Block\Frontend\News" name="newscoll.collall" template="Custom_News::news.phtml" /> 
       </referenceContainer>  
    </body>
</page>
```

**Hope this helps you out**

Comment: oh well done bro. you are amazing developer. it works... thanks again.

Comment: Glad to help you out !!!